# Moodle "upload" button of my site doesn't function inside android webview

Tags: android-webview

I am developing an android application. I have used webview to load my moodle site; everything is fine but the "upload" button doe not function! When for example I click on the "upload" button to upload my photo in profile of moodle, nothing happens.
I have included the following in the manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />


<!--
Allows Glide to monitor connectivity status and restart failed requests if users go from a disconnected to a connected network state.
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

And the following lines have been added to the MainActivity:

```
<if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        int hasCameraPermission = 
checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
        Log.d(TAG, "has camera permission: " + hasCameraPermission);
        int hasRecordPermission = 
checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO);
        Log.d(TAG, "has record permission: " + hasRecordPermission);
        int hasAudioPermission = 
checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS);
        Log.d(TAG, "has audio permission: " + hasAudioPermission);
        List<String> permissions = new ArrayList<>();
        if (hasCameraPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            permissions.add(Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
        }
        if (hasRecordPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            permissions.add(Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO);
        }
        if (hasAudioPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            permissions.add(Manifest.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS);
        }

        if (!permissions.isEmpty()) {
            requestPermissions(permissions.toArray(new 
String[permissions.size()]),111);

        }
    }
```

The following were also added to the webView activity:

```
        wvs.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            @Override
            public void onPermissionRequest(final PermissionRequest request) {
                SiteActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        request.grant(request.getResources());
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onPermissionRequestCanceled(PermissionRequest 
request) {
// The following line was underlined red so I commented it out!                   
//Log.d(TAG, "onPermissionRequestCanceled");
            }
        });
```

After adding the above lines, when I run the app, I am asked to give permission but then a white page opens in webview and nothing happens!

Also, recording audio and video does not function inside the moodle site running in a webview! This may also help to find out the issue!

Would you please help me to eliminate the problem.
I highly appreciate your help.
Faramarz

Comment: check this link it may be helpful : https://inducesmile.com/android-programming/how-to-upload-file-in-webview-in-android/

Comment: Thanks a million for your help. This will be souseful for developing my future apps. But the problem is that moodle has already done this. I am only loading the moodle site in webview and the upload button in moodle does nothing. I donot know what to do! Do I have to change moodle codes or I must do something in android studio. I welcome your comments. Kindest regards.